# How to push submodule changes into another repository

Tags: git, git-submodules

I have read this [documentation](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/Git-Tools-Submodules) and didn't find answer for subject question.

My remote repository consists 3rd party submodules, those submodules changed and changes should be pushed into the my repository. As well I need to fetch new data from submodules.

Does GIT provide something for that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your repo don't **contain** any submodule's code, it only store a pointer to some commit in your submodule

So, if you want to take in modifications from 3rd party submodules, you should
`$ cd /path/to/submodule/in/your/work/tree    # enter your submodule directory
$ git fetch origin                           # update
$ git checkout origin/master                 # take in the modifications
$ cd /path/to/your/work/tree
$ git add /path/to/submodule/in/your/work/tree # add your modification for submodule pointer
$ git commit -m "update xxx module to x.x.x.x" # commit`

HOPE I CAN HELP YOU!

Comment: It works, but how to fetch data from submodule origin after checkout (step 3) ?

Comment: @Dmitry after you `git fetch origin` in submodule, you **already** fetched  remote repo updates to your local repo, so after step 2, "fetching data from submodule origin" has already been done. if you want to change `master` in submodule, you can `get checkout master; git reset --hard origin/master` in submodule directory, but be careful, Any changes to tracked files(of cause, in submodule) in the working tree are **discarded**, see here: https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-reset.html

Comment: This approach seems not working, because I can't commit changes nor clone repository.  git clone url; git submodule update --init; And then: Cloning into 'test/src/github.com/guelfey/go.dbus'...
remote: Reusing existing pack: 951, done.
remote: Total 951 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (951/951), 314.59 KiB | 253 KiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (583/583), done.
fatal: reference is not a tree: 562e287d99da12094e555597aba99b93a3ad5cce
Unable to checkout '562e287d99da12094e555597aba99b93a3ad5cce' in submodule path 'test/src/github.com/guelfey/go.dbus'

Comment: Then I can make git checkout origin/master; inside module and get source tree in 'detached HEAD' state. But after git add; git commit; git push; on other computer I have same error message and no changed data. Git worked in client/server mode between two devs.

Comment: Unable to checkout 'xxx' mostly means you didn't push commit to **your** submodule repo. Suppose the url of 3rd party library(named B) repo is `http://not/on/your/sever/B.git`, your repo url is `http://this/is/your/repo/server/A.git`, you fetch submodule B from `http://not/on/your/sever/B.git` and then push to `http:/this/is/your/repo/server/B.git`, add submodule B to A `git submodule add http://this/is/your/repo/server/B.git path/to/B/directory`. when `http://not/on/your/server/B.git` updated, you should first **commit** those updates to your `http://this/is/your/repo/server/B.git`

Comment: Thank you for detail explanation. So, I need to fork http://not/on/your/sever/B.gi first and only then use it as submodule (http:/this/is/your/repo/server/B.git).